# Finding match by negating (based on a missing string)

Tags: regex, string, conditional-statements, mime

I've been googling a lot about this.
What I'm trying to achieve is the next:
I have to check in a regex condition if a MIME is NOT of a specific type.

For example, I have recevied the next message:

```
image/png, image/jpeg, document/pdf
```

I would like to detect the `document/pdf` part only
, which is a MIME type, a string, that does NOT start with image/

But no matter how hard I looked, tried and played around with the RegExBody software, I just utterly fail to match it..

I'm posting this in despair and hopes that maybe an expert regex could help me out..

I tried many approaches, mainly:
Finding out the non-image type, regardless if there is one or not.

It just refuses to work.
I tried positive lookahead and negative lookahead. But I probably used it wrong somehow. I can't post the examples because I have tried and deleted so many. The one that seemed really close to working was `\b(?:(?!image/\w+))\w+\b` but it just persists on selecting the second part of the non-matching pattern. 
If I use: `image/png`
It gets the: `png`
Which means it would still return true although I meant it to ignore `image/` types..

Comment: Please show us sample input and expected outputs/conclusions.

Comment: Please don't add [solved] to titles here - the tick against the answer is sufficient to mark the question as resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, how does it hurt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have added a `/\w+` part after `\w+` to match your substring:

```
\b(?!image/)\w+/\w+\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oM2eR9/1)

Pattern details:

- `\b`  - word boundary
- `(?!image/)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is `image/` right after the current location
- `\w+/\w+` - 1+ word characters followed with `/` and again 1+ word characters
- `\b`  - a trailing word boundary

Comment: Thank you very much! Quick answer + it's working! :)) I'm trying to select your answer as the correct one

Comment: You have, if you also find my answe helpful please consider upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

This search regular expression when replaced with '' will return document/pdf.

```
(?:image\/\w+)[,\s]*
```